# How to get custom object sub list individual item position in parent custom object array list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexof

I have a Class called StudentData. The StudentData class having params like id(unique), name, address etc. Now I have a two ArrayList of StudentData class like one contains ArrayList of 10 items and another one contains ArrayList of 50 items.
Now my question is, Is there any better way to find out the individual position of 10 items in 50 item list ?

This is how I'm trying to do it, please correct me if I'm wrong

```
ArrayList<Integer> allId = new ArrayList<>();
outerLoop:
 for (int i = 0; i < totalList.getSmallList().size(); i++) {
    for (int position = 0; position < totalList.getBigList().size(); position++) {
         if (totalList.getSmallList().get(i).getID() == totalList.getBigList().get(position).getID()) {
         allId.add(totalList.getBigList().get(position).getID());
         continue outerLoop;
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Is there any reason to add the `id` to the result list (instead of the `position`)? As for retrieving the `id`s, it is sufficient to iterate through the small list only.

Comment: @Izruo No, I just need to get the position of individual item, can you just correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did not get you wrong. you want to get  the indices (of bigList)of the matched items in the small list and add them to a separate allIdd;

```
ArrayList<Integer> allId = new ArrayList<>();
outerLoop:
 for (int i = 0; i < totalList.getSmallList().size(); i++) {
    for (int position = 0; position < totalList.getBigList().size(); position++) {
         if (totalList.getSmallList().get(i).getID() == totalList.getBigList().get(position).getID()) {
         allId.add(posotion);
         continue outerLoop;
       }
     }
   }
```

**Edit:**

from your comments:
add `bigList` to the `listAdapter` and the above will give you what to highlight

Comment: what I'm trying to do is, I need to show a listview of biglist items but I want to highlight the items those comes under smallList, so I need to get the position if i'm not wrong

Comment: yes. you are doing it right. add your `biglist` to the `listView` adapter and now you have the positions you want to highlight.so my answer will work

Comment: then how can I find out if I click on highlighted item ?

Comment: implement onItemClickListsner 
and add this check to it
if(allId.contains(posisiion)){
//a highlighted item is clicked
}

Comment: Thanks buddy, It works like charm!      In Adapter, i'm highlighting this way:-                                                    
 for (Integer newPos : AllPos) {
                if (adapterPosition == newPos) {
                    viewHolder.view.setHighlight // example
                }
            }                                                                                                                                    any better way ?